# Reloading tab bar appearance

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I am trying to reload the tab bar after the user changes the appearance of the app from light to dark mode and vice versa. I am able to update everything in the app except the tab bar. I don't want to force the user to close the app.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With iOS 13 you can override `traitCollectionDidChange(_:)` in UITabBarController to make changes. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623516-traitcollectiondidchange).

Example:

```
class TabBarControllerViewController: UITabBarController {

    ...

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice to see apple finally incorporate dark mode :)

Comment: `traitCollectionDidChange` will be called when any trait is changed, this can happen when the device is rotated for example. You should be calling super and then checking which trait has changed. From iOS 13 you can call `if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/3238081-hasdifferentcolorappearance), prior to that you need to use `if previousTraitCollection?.userInterfaceStyle != traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {`

Answer (score 7):

If you try to look at [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance) about `UIAppearance`, you'll see the note:

> iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t
>   change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. *To change
>   the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view
>   from the view hierarchy and then put it back.*

Based on this note you can change appearance with a little trick by remove and immediately set back the most top view in the hierarchy after applying changes to appearance:

```
guard let currentView = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController?.view,
    let superview = currentView.superview else { return }

UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .green

currentView.removeFromSuperview()
superview.addSubview(currentView)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I haven't considered removing the root-view and re-adding it which now seems fairly obvious. Thanks again!

Comment: This seems very hacky.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that **none** of the answers here are correct (at time of writing). When assigning a colour to a view you simply need to make sure a dark mode colour is set and the system will automatically update it when the user changes mode.

Two main options for this:

1. Use an asset catalog and make sure Appearances is set to 'Any, Dark', set both colours and assign it to the tab bar:

[image]

`tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "tabBarBackground")`

2. Or you can programmatically set a dark mode colour:

`tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.withDarkModeColor(.black)`

Comment: Agree with your solution #1, color asset should be used in theme changed situation.

Answer (score -1):

You can just set the color of your tabBar using the `tabBar.backgroundColor`-property:

```
self?.tabBar.backgroundColor
```

---

Please make sure you are updating the background color on the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
   self?.tabBar.backgroundColor = newAppearanceColor
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was that I had not reloaded the tab bar in the root-view (see the answer above.) Thank you thought!